# Using FSL.AppointmentBookingService.GetSlots() method in Unit Tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, managed-package, field-service-lightning, fsl

I'm trying to verify the validity of my endpoint that is using `FSL.AppointmentBookingService.GetSlots()` method in Unit Tests. No matter what data I'm preparing method is always returning me an empty List. The only way that worked for me was to use `@IsTest(seeAllData=true)` but that is not acceptable. Is there any way to make this method work in Unit Tests without `@IsTest(seeAllData=true)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the test class below. I've added an explanation of the code as comments inline

```
@isTest
private class testGetSlotsExample {

@TestSetup
static void setup(){

    // Create Admin user for RunAs purposes to create users and assign permission sets
    Id adminProfileId = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator'].Id;
    User adminUser = new User(
        ProfileId = adminProfileId,
        FirstName = 'System',
        LastName = 'Administrator',
        UserName = System.now().getTime() + '@sse.demo',
        Alias = 'sadmin',
        Email = 'swetha@sse.demo',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        LocaleSidKey = 'nl_NL',
        TimeZoneSidKey = UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID(),
        UserPermissionsSupportUser = true
    );        

    // Add FSL Admin Permissions if not already to running user (assuming admin)
    System.runAs(adminUser){
        // Lookup the Field Service Admin Permissions permission set
        PermissionSet psSFSAdmin = [
            select Id from PermissionSet where Name ='FSL_Admin_Permissions'];

        // Associate it to the current user
        try {
            insert new PermissionSetAssignment(
                PermissionSetId = psSFSAdmin.Id,
                AssigneeId = UserInfo.getUserId()
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Perm set already assigned, continue
        }
    }        
    // Create foundation records for scheduling

    // Scheduling Policy - this can be extended with additional Work Rules and Objectives
    FSL__Scheduling_Policy__c sp = new FSL__Scheduling_Policy__c(
        Name = 'Policy For Testing'
    );
    insert sp;

    // Operating Hours for both availability and time slots
    List<OperatingHours> ohs = new List<OperatingHours>();

    // Operating Hours for availability
    OperatingHours ohAvailability = new OperatingHours(
        Name = 'Availability Hours',
        TimeZone = UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID()
    );
    ohs.add(ohAvailability);

    // Operating Hours for time slots
    OperatingHours ohTimeSlots = new OperatingHours(
        Name = 'Time Slot Hours',
        TimeZone = UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID()
    );
    ohs.add(ohTimeSlots);   
    
    insert ohs;

    // Create time slots for operating hours
    List<TimeSlot> timeSlots = new List<TimeSlot>();
    timeSlots.add(new TimeSlot(
        OperatingHoursId = ohAvailability.Id,
        DayOfWeek = 'Monday',
        StartTime = Time.newInstance(9,0,0,0),
        EndTime = Time.newInstance(17,0,0,0)
    ));
    
    timeSlots.add(new TimeSlot(
        OperatingHoursId = ohTimeSlots.Id,
        DayOfWeek = 'Monday',
        StartTime = Time.newInstance(9,0,0,0),
        EndTime = Time.newInstance(13,0,0,0)
    ));
    timeSlots.add(new TimeSlot(
        OperatingHoursId = ohTimeSlots.Id,
        DayOfWeek = 'Monday',
        StartTime = Time.newInstance(13,0,0,0),
        EndTime = Time.newInstance(17,0,0,0)
    ));      

    insert timeSlots;        

    // Create Service Territory
    ServiceTerritory st = new ServiceTerritory(
        Name = 'Test Service Territory',
        isActive = true,
        Street = 'Kerstraat 1',
        PostalCode = '1017 GA',
        City = 'Amsterdam',
        Country = 'NL',
        OperatingHoursId = ohAvailability.Id
    );
    insert st;

    // Create user for a field technician resource with the right permission sets
    System.runAs(adminUser){
        Id profileId = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'Minimum Access - Salesforce Field Service Technician CDO'].Id;
        User tech = new User(
            ProfileId = profileId,
            FirstName = 'Field',
            LastName = 'Technician',
            UserName = System.now().getTime() + '@ftech.demo',
            Alias = 'tsttech1',
            Email = 'tsttech1@ftech.demo',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            LocaleSidKey = 'nl_NL',
            TimeZoneSidKey = UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID(),
            UserPermissionsSupportUser = true
        );

        insert tech;

        List<PermissionSet> sfsPermSets = [
                select Id from PermissionSet where Name = 'FSL_Resource_Permissions' OR Name ='FSL_Resource_License'];

        List<PermissionSetAssignment> permSetAssigns = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
        for (PermissionSet sfsPermSet : sfsPermSets){
            permSetAssigns.Add(
                new PermissionSetAssignment(
                    PermissionSetId = sfsPermSet.Id,
                    AssigneeId = tech.Id
                )
            );
        }

        insert permSetAssigns;
    }

    // Lookup the user that was created in the runAs context
    User tech = [
        select Id, FirstName,LastName from User where  Alias = 'tsttech1'];

    // Create Service Resource
    ServiceResource sr = new ServiceResource(
        Name = tech.FirstName + ' ' + tech.LastName,
        isActive = true,
        IsOptimizationCapable = true, // This is important otherwise the resource is not available for scheduling
        ResourceType = 'T',
        RelatedRecordId = tech.Id
    );
    insert sr;

    // Make resource part of the service territory
    insert new ServiceTerritoryMember(
        ServiceTerritoryId = st.Id,
        ServiceResourceId = sr.Id,
        TerritoryType = 'P',
        EffectiveStartDate = System.now().addDays(-3)
    );

    // Create Work Type record 
    insert new WorkType(
        Name = 'Maintenance',
        ShouldAutoCreateSvcAppt = true,
        FSL__Due_Date_Offset__c = 60*24*7, // 1 week in minutes
        DurationType = 'Minutes',
        EstimatedDuration = 60
    );

}

@IsTest
static void startTest(){
    
    // Retrieve Work Type Id
    Id wtId = [select Id from WorkType where Name = 'Maintenance'].Id;

    // Create Work Order. Service Appointment is created via the Work Type
    WorkOrder wo = new WorkOrder(
        WorkTypeId = wtId,
        Subject = 'Test',
        Street = 'Kerkstraat 2',
        PostalCode = '3581 RD',
        City = 'Utrecht',
        Country = 'NL'
    );
    insert wo;

    // Get the details for getSlots
    OperatingHours oh = [select Id, TimeZone from OperatingHours where Name = 'Time Slot Hours'];
    Timezone tz = Timezone.getTimeZone(oh.TimeZone);
    Id spId = [select Id from FSL__Scheduling_Policy__c limit 1].Id;
    
    Test.startTest();

    // Lookup the service appointment and retrieve slots
    Id saId = [select Id from ServiceAppointment where ParentRecordId = :wo.Id].Id;
    List<FSL.AppointmentBookingSlot> slots = FSL.AppointmentBookingService.getSlots(saId, spId, oh.Id, tz, false);  

    System.debug(slots);

    // Perform the necessary assets!

    Test.stopTest();
}}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I was missing `FSL_Resource_Permissions` on Resource-related User.